# MacVim - how to make mouse based selection be "visual mode"?

Tags: vim, gvim, macvim

Sometimes I select text in vim using the mouse.

I'd like that selection to be treated the same as a visual mode selection, so I can immediately start running commands against it.

Is there a way I can do this in MacVim ?

EDIT: I've tried using `mouse=a` and it doesnt seem to help. If i select text using visual mode and the keyboard, when I yank it by typing 'y', the text loses the selection, but doesnt delete from my buffer. When I do it with the mouse, the text deletes.

Comment: I don't know about MacVim, but usually this is done by `:set mouse=a`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've tried using `mouse=a` and it doesnt seem to help. If i select text using visual mode and the keyboard, when I yank it by typing 'y', the text loses the selection, but doesnt delete from my buffer. When I do it with the mouse, the text deletes.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use this:

```
:set mouse+=a
```

This will tell vim to use the mouse for visual mode.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've tried using `mouse=a` and it doesnt seem to help. If i select text using visual mode and the keyboard, when I yank it by typing 'y', the text loses the selection, but doesnt delete from my buffer. When I do it with the mouse, the text deletes.

Comment: If you want the text to be deleted from the buffer you should type 'd' instead of 'y'. This puts the content of the selection in the clipboard as well.

Comment: thanks but I don't want the text to delete when I type `y`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on mswin:

Mouse went into select mode because of `selectmode=mouse,key`
which was being set by `behave=mswin` in $vim\_vimrc.
That was causing mouse selected text to be deleted when I typed a `y` to yank.

I added this to $home\_vimrc:

```
"let visual work  
set keymodel-=stopsel  
set selectmode-=mouse
```

That allowed the mouse to go into visual mode when I select with the mouse
so that yank doesn't delete the selection.